# Type mismatch; found `Message`, required `T`

Tags: generics, kotlin, abstract-class

In my code I have a method `publishMessage` requiring type extending from class `Message`. In this method `publish` is called which requires `message` of type `T`.

This gives the error > Type mismatch; found `Message`, required `T`.

Does this have to do with `T` that need to be an extension of class `Message` which is declared with the method? I do not see why this can not be done.

In my head such a parameter with type `T` can be anything

> Myclass

```
fun <T : Message> publishMessage(topic: String, type: Class<T>, message: Message) {
    val node = findOrCreateNode(topic, type)
    node.publish(message) // Type mismatch; found `Message`, required `T` .
}
```

> Node class

```
fun publish(message: T) {
   // Implementation
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my head such a parameter with type T can be anything

Yes, it can be anything, but the compiler wants to be sure there's nothing wrong with your types. So you'll have to either create your Node object like this `Node<Message>()` or change `publishMessage` method signature to `fun <T : Message> publishMessage(topic: String, type: Class<T>, message: T)`. In this case the compiler can guarantee type safety and the error will go away.

Comment: `but the compiler wants to be sure there's nothing wrong with your types` Why should the compiler have doubts about the validity of the parameter while it can be anything?

Comment: Well... it can be anything during object creation. However when the object is created you have to work with this particular type. If you declare your class as Node<T> then you can create an object of type Node<Message>, you also can create an object of type Node<String>, Node<Any>, etc. And method parameter 'message' of type T becomes Message, String or Any respectively. If you create an object of type Node<Message> and try to pass String to the method, which now expects Message and not String, then you're in big trouble (this is basically huge problem of dynamic typed languages). @Klyner

Comment: You might wonder "But there's <T : Message> and the parameter type is Message so if I pass it to T everything should be fine". And you would be absolutely right! However it's okay from your point of view, not the compiler's. At this particular point of time compiler sees two different types, that's why you get the error. Maybe some day it will know that your code is safe, but today it's not able to determine that. @Klyner

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I think it lands. So `T` refers to the type that was used with the object creation for the Node<T> which by then is defined and can no longer be changed for that particular object.